# Use an existing Drupal site to create a new site

Tags: database

Today I tried to copy a existing Drupal site for creating a new one on a other domain-name.

The problem: the new website still uses the old DB. So if I create a new user for example, this user also show up in the other (first) website. The same thing for deleting content.

What did I do:

1. Created a new DB for the new website.
2. Backup the DB form the old website and find/replace the domainname
   to the new domain-name is the sql-file.
3. Import the SQL into the new DB
4. Copy the website-drupal folders from the old website - change the
   setting-file in map DEFAULT with the new DB info. (so it connects to
   the new DB - after that i FTP the files to the new host.

When I visit the new domain-name a copy of the website showed up and I could login. The first thing I wanted to do was delete all content and users. But seems to be the actions I do in the new website also happens in the old website.

I did a search on Google and find out I did have to change some info in SQL-file. First time I did not do that so I did everything again... so also with step 2)

But the new website seems to be still connecting to the old website. I erased the DB of the new site and the website is still working. So it makes still contact with the OLD DB.

So changing the settings-file and SQL file was not enough.

What did I do wrong??

Any tips, links are welcome!

Comment: Which settings file did you change? was it default.settings.php, or was it settings.php?

Comment: It was settings.php ofcourse :)

Comment: I think the settinngs from the old settings.php will persist until you clear the cache.  Have you tried to clear the cache?

Comment: Yes i tried clearing cache, but maybe to late... I'm now trying it again..

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, you that settings.php should be the ticket, but to really trouble shoot it, it would be easier to see the code. But because that contains your DB connection, that's not something that you should be sharing with others. However, if your having troubles, you could always try going about this a different way.

You could start with a blank db, and toss your settings.php file. That will cause Drupal to think it isn't installed yet, and will take you through the install process. Once your done with that and have a clean Drupal site running on a clean DB, then you can dump your data from your old site into the new DB, which should transfer your data over, but you'll have a fresh settings.php file. That might be easier way to go about it.

Comment: Hi Jance, thanks for response. I'm now trying to start with a earlier version... Because the old site started also from a other existing website. With the old one i didn't had that problem. If it doesnt work i try your hint.

Comment: Jance, starting from a earlier version worked :) So i gonna work with that version now. Thanks for the hint!